# Передача ирреальности индикативом (в переводах на русский язык)

Tags: наклонение

Уже давно стараюсь понять какие приемы может использовать переводчик при передаче оригинала, а какие нет. На этом сайте мне дали хороший комментарий:

> При переводе важно не просто донести смысл оригинала (это верная
>   рекомендация), а сделать это по возможности точно: уяснив точный
>   смысл, сформулировать его средствами второго языка — так, как сказал
>   бы в той же ситуации его носитель. (cit.)

Тем не менее ко мне не приходит понимание следующего вопроса: правильно со стороны переводчика "искажать" перспективу? 
Хочу сказать: если в оригинале используется сослагательное наклонение для передачи гипотетической/ирреальной ситуации, может переводчик это передавать через индикатив?

Пример:

(В оригинале в двух примерах используется сослагательное наклонение.)

Русской перевод:

> (1) Что ты скажешь, если твоя дочь выйдет замуж за американца?
>
> (2) Журналист спросил автогонщика, каковы его последние мысли, если
>   ему суждено умереть в автокатастрофе.

Как вы думаете, если в русском языке есть специальное наклонение для выражения ирреальности, почему переводчик не делает из него употребление? Почему не переводит как:

> (1а) Что **бы** ты **сказал**, **если** **бы** твоя дочь **вышла** замуж за американца?
>
> (2а) Журналист спросил автогонщика, каковы **бы** **были** его последние
>   мысли, **если** **бы** ему **было суждено умереть** в автокатастрофе.

Если в примерах речь идет о гипотетической ситуации, o том что what if, почему переводчик приходит к идее использовать индикатив? Или я совсем ошибаюсь и это абсолютно приемлемо для русского языка?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> Как вы думаете, если в русском языке есть специальное наклонение для
> выражения ирреальности, почему переводчик не делает из него
> употребление? Почему не переводит как:

Если одним словом, то зачем писать/говорить много служебных слов если та же мысль выражается проще?! Ваши вторые варианты не добавляют смысла, но производят впечатление какой-то неестественности, избыточности.

> Уже давно стараюсь понять какие приемы может использовать переводчик
> при передаче оригинала, а какие нет. На этом сайте мне дали хороший
> комментарий:

Мне кажется, вы все достаточно хорошо понимаете, только пытаетесь найти ответы на умозрительные, не актуальные для живого общения на русском вопросы.

> Тем не менее ко мне не приходит понимание следующего вопроса:
> правильно со стороны переводчика "искажать" перспективу?

Это было бы неправильно, но тут нет искажения. Обычный носитель русского не связывает выбор грамматического наклонения с "искажением перспективы". Он просто понимает, что речь идет о каком-то событии, не состоявшемся событии, остальное домысливает по ситуации или восполняет лексическими средствами. .

Русский язык вообще бедный на всякие грамматические категории (кроме формообразующих, флективных) , но зато весьма гибкий, одна и та же мысль может передаваться с помощью разных синтаксических форм. И выбирается всегда та, которая проще или естественнее в конкретной ситуации. Жестких предписаний сравнительно немного.

> Хочу сказать: если в оригинале используется сослагательное наклонение
> для передачи гипотетической/ирреальной ситуации, может переводчик это
> передавать через индикатив?

Может. Если это не препятствует пониманию. А почему нет? Тут, правда, сильно зависит от языка-источника. Есть вещи, которые в принципе невозможно передать на русском.

> При переводе важно не просто донести смысл оригинала (это верная
> рекомендация), а сделать это по возможности точно: уяснив точный
> смысл, сформулировать его средствами второго языка — так, как сказал
> бы в той же ситуации его носитель. (cit.)

Это верная мысль, но она не должна превращаться в догму. Уже сказал, что есть вещи, которые не переносятся буквально и это огромная проблема переводов вообще, не нашего уровня.

> Если в примерах речь идет о гипотетической ситуации, o том что what
> if, почему переводчик приходит к идее использовать индикатив? Или я
> совсем ошибаюсь и это абсолютно приемлемо для русского языка?

Это не просто приемлемо, это необходимо, чтобы тексты звучали на русском, а не на языке иностранца, пытающегося говорить на русском, плохо его зная.

Я немножечко отвлекусь, надеюсь, этот текст не доставит вам больших сложностей.
Вы просто оперируете понятиями европейских языков с жесткими принципами выбора глагольных форм. А попробуйте объяснить это, скажем, китайцу, где вообще нет не то что глагольных форм, а само понятие глагола сильно отличается от нашего? Русский занимает промежуточное положение между, скажем, английским, где использование глагольных форм жестко закреплено ситуацией, и некоторыми азиатскими, где такого понятия в нашем понимании нет вообще. Жестко упорядочить несколькими правилами невозможно. Просто доверяйте в этих случаях чутью переводчика.

> (2) Журналист спросил автогонщика, каковы его последние мысли, если
> ему суждено умереть в автокатастрофе.

Здесь я бы сказал "будут последние мысли". Вот здесь использование одного глагольного времени вместо другого, пожалуй, неверно. Понимаете, "последние мысли" - это понятно, что перед смертью, но стоит изменить "мысли" на, скажем, "желания", "распоряжения" - и становится неясно, о чем речь.

Сравните

> Журналист спросил автогонщика, какое есть завещание, на случай, если
> ему суждено умереть в автокатастрофе.
>
> Журналист спросил автогонщика, какое будет завещание, на случай, если
> ему суждено умереть в автокатастрофе.

В первом случае - имеющееся завещание, уже написанное, во втором - гипотетическое.

Я подчеркнуто передал семантику высказываний в связи с грамматикой условного наклонения. В живой речи, возможно, сказали бы чуть проще, но смысл, думаю, понятен.

Я это не для того сказал, чтобы на ошибку указать. Всё это говорит о том, что в русском "наклонения" часто передаются совсем не теми средствами, которые вы хотите применить. Как и многое другое. Я думаю, это вам будет важно.

Comment: большое спасибо! я сделаю итог правильно я Вас поняла или нет: примеры (1) и (2) абсолютно корректно можно использовать. то что ситуация гипотетическия/ирреальная можно понять из контекста/дополнительных лексических средств/....... 
PD: извините что я может глупые вопросы ставлю. мне просто трудно понять такие вещи, потому что мы никогда не передаем через индикатив деиствие, которое еще не совершилось в реальном мире

Comment: Anonym Да, абсолютно правильно. Ситуацию можно назвать ирреальной (с точки зрения человека другой культуры или лингвиста), но русский просто не задумается над этим, он поймет все правильно, исходя из того, что говорящий/пишущий умеет логически мыслить и не будет с живым человеком говорить о его смерти как о уже свершившемся событии. Можете назвать это "контекстом" или "ситуацией".

Comment: *извините что я может глупые вопросы ставлю.* - сейчас нет, абсолютно не глупый.  Про "неактуальность" я говорил в связи с вашими вопросами себе, о том, какими методами вы пытаетесь разобраться в грамматике русского. Я сам-то эти вещи начал понимать только с вашей помощью, В живом общении они не нужны. Наверное эти тонкости употребления описаны где-то в специальных курсах грамматики, но это чисто академическая постановка вопроса, реальное ли там действие, или  ирреальное. Важно это для переводчиков **с русского на другие языки**, с другой грамматикой, но на русском всё понятно без лишних слов.

Answer (score 1):

Событие, отнесенное к будущему времени, может рассматриваться **как ирреальное** (условие  не осуществилось, хотя может осуществиться в будущем) или как **гипотетическое** (с возможностью реализации  в будущем). В первом случае используется  **сослагательное наклонение**, а во втором — **изъявительное наклонение или инфинитив**.

Соответственно, мы имеем **синонимические формы с одинаковым смыслом** и вследствие этого  возможность выбора,  то есть **обозначаем ирреальность** с помощью сослагательного наклонения  или **используем будущее время изъявительного наклонения**. Формы изъявительного наклонения или инфинитива  более предпочтительны ввиду меньшего объема.

Но такая ситуация возможна  не всегда. **Только сослагательное наклонение** используется в тех случаях, когда условие **не осуществилось и осуществиться уже не может** (контрфактические предложения), например: Если бы не было дождя, мы пошли бы гулять.

**Пример 1**

(1) Что бы ты сказал, если бы твоя дочь вышла замуж за американца? (2) Что ты скажешь, если твоя дочь выйдет замуж за американца? Смысл вопроса один и тот же: Как ты   относишься к подобным бракам.

**Пример 2**

(1) Журналист спросил автогонщика, каковы **будут** его последние мысли, если  ему суждено  умереть в автокатастрофе.  **Примечание**: суждено умереть (**наст. время**) — это устойчивый оборот со значением  уже сделанного предсказания судьбы.

(2) Журналист спросил автогонщика, каковы были бы  его последние мысли, если  ему было бы суждено  умереть в автокатастрофе.

Смысл не меняется, но первый вариант короче и понятнее.

Comment: Вы сейчас своими терминами окончательно запутаете человека. Для неё "ирреальный" - это грамматическая категория.